# Physical interpretation of Probability Current vanishing inside Potential Barrier

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In a Tunneling problem, if the $E_o<V$, we can show that the scattering wavefunction inside a rectangular barrier is a decaying exponential. The solution being real implies that the probability current $J$ is zero at every point inside the barrier.

From equation of continuity,

$\frac{\partial|\psi|^2}{\partial t}=0$

Does this mean that the probability density at each point inside the barrier is fixed? (Clearly it can't be so). How exactly is this to be interpreted?

Answer (score 1):

> Does this mean that the probability density at each point inside the barrier is fixed?

Yes.

> (Clearly it can't be so). How exactly is this to be interpreted?

The solution you mentioned (time-independent decaying exponential) is a solution of the time-independent Schroedinger equation
$$
\hat{H}\psi = E\psi
$$
Since the solutions of this equation depend on time only via factor $e^{\frac{Et}{i\hbar}}$, the resulting probability density $|\psi|^2$ is time-independent.

To obtain time-dependent probability density and non-zero probability current, you can attempt to solve time-dependent Schroedigner equation
$$
\partial_t\psi = \frac{1}{i\hbar}\hat{H}\psi
$$
for initial condition $\psi(x,t_0)$ that is no equal to above $\psi$ function, for example some localized wave packet. But this is quite difficult and may require numeric computer calculation, so it rarely occurs in textbooks.